# Created new WidgetKit extension to app: SwiftUI preview not working with "appex must be in an app"

Tags: swiftui, watchos, widgetkit

I'm on Xcode 14.0.1 on macOS 12.6.

I'm trying to create a new watch complication in my existing app with WidgetKit, starting with adding a Widget Extension template target to my project.

This generated a new folder with an intent definition file, an Assets file, an Info.plist file, and a SwiftUI file.  The SwiftUI file refuses to preview, with the error

```
AppExtensionNeedsContainingAppError<XcodeGraphSource>: MyWatchExtension.appex must be in an app

The app extension "MyWatchExtension.appex" needs to be embedded in an app in order to use previews
```

I'm able to compile the target and run it in the watchOS simulator just fine.  Am I missing a crucial step somewhere?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I also have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error because I accidentally added my complication extension to the watch extension instead of the watch app.

So, if your project uses legacy structure and contains `watchOS` app with embedded extension, make sure you embedded your `WidgetKit` target into the app in **Build Phases > Target Dependencies**.

Comment: That's it. Also make sure that the app identifier does not contain the WatchKit extension

Comment: "accidentally"? No, you did everything as Xcode told you to, you physically cannot unclick the extension selection. Same goes for @Sn0wfreeze comment, it automatically puts the extension as the bundle ID and you cannot change that before it has actually been created. There is no way the folks at Apple use the leftover tools that they provide us, otherwise they'd notice how dumb this all is

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message. For me, the problem was that I had started with a "WatchOS" only app template and then added a WidgetKit target for "iOS" by accident. In this case, there was indeed no app for the iOS WidgetKit target.

Later, I re-created everything and created a "WatchOS" WidgetKit target. Then the preview was running fine.

Could you have done something similar?