# Xcode Widget Extension Cannot Preview in WatchOS

Tags: xcode, widget, watchos

I am adding a Widget Extension (named Complication) to my WatchOS app. When creating the widget, I am not able to select an application in the field "Embed in Application". The app name shows up, but I can only select "None".

When I want to preview the widget, the following error message comes up:

> AppExtensionNeedsContainingAppError:
> ComplicationExtension.appex must be in an app
>
> The app extension "ComplicationExtension.appex" needs to be embedded
> in an app in order to use previews

What can I do to get it to work? I added the app in the Target Membership but that does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Answered similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76467859/1746142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to follow the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76467859/1203713

1. Add the watchOS Widget Extension
2. Make sure the extension is embedded in the watchOS App and not in the WatchKit Extension
3. Make sure the bundle identifier does not contain .watchkitapp.watchkitextension

Then it worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue first in my project (Watch only app). I figured that after selecting File > New > Target **I also had to select WatchOS** on the top before clicking "Widget Extension" otherwise I ran into the same problem (by default it added an iOS widget extension). With the right platform selected I was able to choose which app to embed the widget in and the preview worked correctly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34300203)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did it that way and it does not work. Tried it on Xcode 15 and it clearly creates a watchOS Widget Extension which is embedded in the WatchOS Extension